# Is there a way to correlate values stored in 2 variables in bash script?

Tags: shell, echo

I have a xml file. I am extracting 2 variables IP and GUID. I am doing that using sed command. The values get extracted fine. I am trying to print the value of $ip with corresponding $guid. The IPs are getting written in ips.txt

I am using following command

```
for IP in ips.txt
        do
        echo "$guid has $ip"
        done
```

But this prints all GUIDs has all the ip instead of GUID 1 has IP1.
Any help on how to solve it?

Comment: Please post the code you're using to extract the variables too.

Comment: `ip=$(sed -nre 's:^.*<s\:key\sname="host_name_port_pair">(.*)\:8089<\/s\:key>.*$:\1:p' peers.xml)`
`guid=$(sed -nre 's:^.*<title>(.*)<\/title>.*$:\1:p' peers.xml)`

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica

Comment: What does `declare -p ip guid` show? Please add it to the question for adequate formatting.